# Create Dynamic PHP Variables (Echoed Out) from JavaScript For Loop

Tags: javascript, php

I am attempting to cut down on some Javascript functions. Right now my current design I dynamic create Year list using Javascript. Now that I have it update the current selected value from the value stored in the database I am wondering if I can duplicate this across all the Year list that I have created. There are 10 in total.

Current code:

```
for (a = 1; a <= 1; a++) {
    console.log("STARTING");
    // reference to a specific dropdown list
    var ddYears = $("#ddYears" + a + "");
    console.log(ddYears);
    var theStartYear = "$we" + a + "startyear";
    console.log(theStartYear);
    var ddCurrentSelectedYear = '<?php echo ' + theStartYear + '; ?>'; // THIS IS THE LINE I'M HAVING TROUBLE WITH
    console.log(ddCurrentSelectedYear);
    var initialOption = $("<option/>");
    if (ddCurrentSelectedYear == "") {
    initialOption.html("Year");
    initialOption.val("");
    initialOption.attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
    ddYears.append(initialOption);
    //Loop and add the Year values to DropDownList.
    for (var i = currentYear; i >= 1920; i--) {
        var option = $("<option />");
        if (i == ddcurrentSelectedYear) {
            option.attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
        option.html(i);
        option.val(i);
        ddYears.append(option);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to "hardcode" the variable so when it iterates through it can pick up from my PHP that value that should already be stored in a variable. I can do it with one value but I would like it to do it for 10 values so I don't have to make 10 separate functions for 1 PHP call. As the 'A' increments the variable is named the same in the backend meaning that value could potentially exist. I am not very good with JavaScript so it may be that my syntax is wrong.

Again, I can't emphasis this enough based off what I have seen on stackoverflow when I do call that line (that has I'm having trouble with it) like shown below it will retrieve a value from my PHP.

```
var ddcurrentSelectedYear =  '<?php echo $we1startyear; ?>';
```

Does anyone see any issues with my JavaScript syntax?

Edit 1: There seems to be some confusion as to what I'm doing so I am placing some code below this that I'm currently using and it works. You will see all that changes is instead of the for loop I'm accessing it as a hardcoded name. The number is the only thing changing in the html selector and the PHP outputted variable. That is the whole purpose of what I'm trying to achieve with the for loop is instead of writing this function 20+ times for a character change have a for loop do the heavy lifting for me.... (Let me reinstate my question - Is there any way to write one function for what I'm currently doing below?

```
$(function () {
            var ddYears = $("#dd1Years");
            var ddCurrentSelectedYear =  '<?php echo $we1startyear; ?>'; 
            // create intial blank option
            var initialOption = $("<option />");
            if (dd1currentSelectedYear == "") {
                initialOption.attr('selected', 'selected');
            }
            initialOption.html("Year");
            initialOption.val("");
            ddYears.append(initialOption);
            //Loop and add the Year values to DropDownList.
            for (var i = currentYear; i >= 1920; i--) {
                var option = $("<option />");
                if (i == dd1currentSelectedYear) {
                    option.attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
                option.html(i);
                option.val(i);
                ddYears.append(option);
            } 
        }
        $(function () {
            var ddYears = $("#dd2Years");
            var ddCurrentSelectedYear =  '<?php echo $we2startyear; ?>'; 
            //Loop and add the Year values to DropDownList.
            for (var i = currentYear; i >= 1920; i--) {
                var option = $("<option />");
                if (i == ddCurrentSelectedYear) {
                    option.attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
                option.html(i);
                option.val(i);
                ddYears.append(option);
            } 
        }
        $(function () {
            var ddYears = $("#dd3Years");
            var ddCurrentSelectedYear =  '<?php echo $we3startyear; ?>'; 
            //Loop and add the Year values to DropDownList.
            for (var i = currentYear; i >= 1920; i--) {
                var option = $("<option />");
                if (i == ddCurrentSelectedYear) {
                    option.attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
                option.html(i);
                option.val(i);
                ddYears.append(option);
            } 
        }
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing when PHP code runs and when JavaScript runs. PHP code runs BEFORE the page is delivered to the browser. Only once it is running in the browser does JavaScript run on the page. You cannot mix the two and pass info back and forth without HTTP requests. The example at the end of your question works because it is ONE WAY. The PHP evaluates as the page is built and hard-codes a static value that is "valid javascript" in the place of that statement.

Comment: @Chase That is why I provided the last example..... If JavaScript code is executing after PHP runs than what I'm asking for is doable. All the variables should already be initialized in the PHP. At this point a JavaScript iterator should be able to go through and retrieve those 'already declared and initialized variables' just as that last independent line has shown me that it can do. 

Like so: '<?php echo $we2startyear; ?>'; 
 '<?php echo $we3startyear; ?>';

Comment: `var ddcurrentSelectedYear =  '<?php echo $we1startyear; ?>'; `  this works, but it sets the variable to some constant that is set before the page is sent to the client browser.  If  use "view page source" or F12 dev tools in Google, the page source will look like `var ddcurrentSelectedYear =  '2012';`  (or `= '';` if  $we1startyear is undefined)

Comment: @DaveS yes that one does work.In my PHP it retrieve that value from the DB. It will return whatever is set in the MySQL DB. If the echo could dynamically create $we2startyear, $we3startyear, etc it should also be able to see if value exist in the PHP already.

I'm not asking for it to call PHP again from JavaScript. The variables already exist on the client side. It is really a matter of my JavaScript syntax being wrong at this point and I'm not sure why. Maybe I'm concatenating wrong.

Comment: what is this line? : `var theStartYear = "$we" + a + "startyear";` 
If you want to read the php variable you need to use `<?php echo ....;?>` as you did for ddCurrentSelecrtedYear. 
And later you use `theStartYear` as if it were a PHP variable, but its a JS variable..

Comment: @AlexAngelico The idea behind that that line is me trying to create the dynamic PHP variable to be later called in the JavaScript loop. I'm trying to create a dynamic retrievable PHP variable. It is supposed to be creating the PHP variable that already exist before the webpage is called so that its value can be accessed. I want to use that output stored in that JS variable "theStartYear" as part of the echo in the PHP in order to have that dynamic PHP variable but its created on the JS side.

Comment: for reading a PHP variable in JS you just `echo` the variable as you did for `ddCurrentSelecrtedYear`. You cannot pass from JS to PHP. What you can do is assign the JS value to an `<input>`   and then read from php once posted. Remember PHP is server side.

Comment: Yes, the PHP side disappears as soon as the page is built and sent.  Only HTML + JS arrives at the client browser.  View Source or F12  dev tools will show this to you.